# Consulta Oracle SQL esquema HR, como sacar una consulta referida a fechas?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

1.Quiero mostrar los empleados que se contrataron en el mes de mayo.

```
select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEES where HIRE_DATE=?????
```

2.Hay otra consulta que me piden los empleados que no tengan comisión pero en where yo hago COMMISSION_PCT=null o '' pero no me funciona no si hay algún método mas sencillo de hacerlo.

Comment: Sugerencia: siempre poner la definición de la tabla sobre la que se consulta para que los tipos de dato usados sean los correctos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la fecha de mayo:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2018/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND TO_DATE ('2018/05/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Para la comision:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE COMMISION_PCT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Para sacar el mes en oracle puedes usar un extract algo así:

```
select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEES where extract(month from HIRE_DATE) = 5
```

y para la otra consulta prueba

```
COMMISSION_PCT is null
```

Comment: Bien super efectivo, así es me sacasteis la duda, ya pude completar la consulta, muchísimas gracias.